# How to create a function to dynamically create list of tuples within a range?

Tags: python

Is there a way to create a function which creates a list of tuples with arguments for:

- number of tuples
- elements per tuple
- beginning range
- ending range

I believe I have most of it:

```
import random

def list_rand_num_tuples(num_of_tups, range_beg, range_end):
    list_tuples = [
        (random.randrange(range_beg, range_end),
         random.randrange(range_beg, range_end),
         random.randrange(range_beg, range_end))
        for i in range(num_of_tups)]
    return list_tuples

# test/display it
print(list_rand_num_tuples(3, 0, 51))
```

but how can this portion be more dynamic?

```
(random.randrange(range_beg, range_end),
 random.randrange(range_beg, range_end),
 random.randrange(range_beg, range_end))
```

For example, can the `length of tuple` / `elements of tuple` argument be provided to loop through this part the appropriate number of times?

Comment: what do you mean by beginning range and ending range

Comment: Making this "more dynamic" at the expense of readability isn't necessarily an improvement.

Comment: What is the issue, exactly? Have you tried anything, done any research? Stack Overflow is not a free code writing service. See: [tour], [ask], [help/on-topic], https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users.

Comment: Yes, I thought my question was reasonable. I had a solution that worked, but figured there was a cleaner way. I asked for help when trying to rework that final piece.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you mean adding an extra parameter for the elements per tuple? You can add another range

```
def list_rand_num_of_tuples(num_tups, num_elements, range_beg, range_end):
    return [tuple(random.randrange(range_beg, range_end)
                  for _ in range(num_elements))
            for _ in range(num_tups)]
```

Answer (score 2):

A possible implementation could use the [`starmap`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.starmap) function from the `itertools` module:

```
import random
import itertools

def list_rand_num_tuples(num_of_tups, range_beg, range_end):
    """
    Generate `num_of_tups` tuples, each containing `num_of_tups` random
    numbers selected from the interval `range_beg..range_end`.
    """
    interval = (range_beg, range_end)
    return [
         tuple(itertools.starmap(random.randrange, [interval] * num_of_tups))
         for _ in range(num_of_tups)
    ]
```

With this implementation,

```
>>> list_rand_num_tuples(3, 0, 10)
```

outputs

```
[(2, 7, 5), (4, 1, 0), (1, 7, 0)]
```

I personally find this much more readable than nested list comprehensions, and it makes use of standard library functionality designed precisely for this purpose.

Comment: It's called `starmap`, not `startmap`.

Comment: if you are going to use itertools you might as well just use `itertools.repeat(interval, num_of_ups)`

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga To each his own. I find the list repetition perfectly readable myself. Both methods having essentially identical time complexities according to `timeit`.

Answer (score 0):

Adding the `elem_per_tuple` variable into the function. Using `lambda` for readability sake so that your nested list comprehension `list_tuples` doesn't look like knotted noodles.

```py
import random

def list_rand_num_tuples(num_of_tups, elem_per_tuple, range_beg, range_end):
    rand = lambda: random.randrange(range_beg, range_end)                   
    return [tuple(rand() for _ in range(elem_per_tuple)) for _ in range(num_of_tups)]


print(list_rand_num_tuples(3, 3, 0, 51))
```

Outputs:

```
[(22, 47, 11), (37, 26, 40), (29, 22, 7)]
```